# Set $A$ partitionable into denumerable sets implies injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $A\ne\emptyset$. I want to prove that if $A$ is partitionable into denumerable sets then there exists an injective function from natural numbers to the set $A$. In the hint of this question it is said that one requires Zorn's lemma to prove it. However, I don't think that I'm doing it right. Here's my approach.

Since $A$ is partitionable into denumerable sets, there exists a collection $\{P_i\}_{i\in I}\subset \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that

- each $P_i$ is denumerable;
- $P_i \cap P_j=\emptyset$ if $i\ne j\in I$;
- $A = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I} P_i$.

Since each $P_i$ is denumerable, there exists an injective function $f_i:\mathbb{N}\to P_i$.

Since the $P_i$ are denumerable, each $P_i$ can be partitioned into finite chains $P_{i_k}$. Then each chain will have an upper bound, and so $P_i$ has a maximal element, which also implies that $P_i$ is finite. Let $x_i \in P_i$ be a maximal element of $P_i$. Since $f_i$ is injective, $f^{-1}(x_i):=k_i\in\mathbb{N}$ exists.

Define

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 
      f_1 & n\in \{1,2,\dots, k_1\} \\
      f_2 & n\in \{k_1+1,k_1+2,\dots, k_2\} \\
      \vdots\\
      f_m & n\in \{k_{m-1}+1,k_{m-1}+2,\dots, k_m\} \\
      \vdots
   \end{cases}
$$

Then $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ is an injection, as required.

My questions are the following:

(1) Can we really say that each $P_i$ can be partitioned into finite chains $P_{i_k}$? I doubt this.

(2) Does there really necessarily exist a maximal element in $A$? If $A$ is partitionable into denumerable sets, this does not imply that $A$ is finite. Then $A$ does not necessarily have a maximal element.

(3) So how should Zorn's lemma be applied here exactly?

Comment: Huh? I believe that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ can be partitioned into denumerable sets $P_i=\mathbb N\times\{i\},\ i\in\mathbb R$ but I don't believe there is a surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R.$

Comment: Perhaps you mean to say that $A$ is partitionable into countably many countable sets?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be "injective function" instead of "surjective function". Editing now.

Comment: Are denumerable sets infinite? Otherwise, the injective version of the question is false as well.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, they are countably infinite, as per my understanding.

Comment: @bof We're given that $A$ is non-empty, so $I$ must be non-empty as well. The empty set, I think, is vacuously partitionable. But how is Zorn's lemma applicable?

Comment: Sorry, I missed "$A\ne\emptyset.$" But the problem as stated now is trivial. If $A$ is partitioned into denumerable sets (and is nonempty), then $A$ contains a denumerable set $P.$ So there is an injective map $f:\mathbb N\to P\subseteq A,$ so $f$ is an injective map from $\mathbb N$ to $A.$

Comment: @bof I thought the other direction was trivial, but probably I was mistaken... It is probably the other direction that needs Zorn's lemma.

Comment: @bof Can't there be an injective map from $\mathbb{N}$ to an uncountable set? Say, $f(n) = n\in \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$. So that even if $A$ cannot be partitioned into denumerable sets, there is an injective map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is false. For each $t\in [0,1),$ define

$$A_t= \{n+t: n \in \mathbb Z\}.$$

Then each $A_t$ is denumerable, the sets $A_t$ are pairwise disjoint, and $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{t\in [0,1)}A_t.$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be "injective function" instead of "surjective function". Editing now.

Comment: @sequence But you still say "It is in my understanding that what needs to be proved is that $A$ is also denumerable." That's clearly false.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I think it's more clear to me that it doesn't have to be denumerable, since by definition a denumerable set $S$ is one which has a corresponding injection from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and not vice versa. @zhw.